# React Native - Could not connect to development server

Tags: react-native

This error is driving me nuts. I have changed the IP in my AppDelegate.m, I am connected to the same wifi on both laptop and iphone, but I still get this error. For some reason it works when I'm on my work wifi but not on my home wifi. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Did you try using localhost and the simulator?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your ip on the file

`node_modules/react-native/Libraries/WebSocket/RCTWebSocketExecutor.m`

change the line

`NSString *URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost:%zd/debugger-proxy?role=client", port];`

change `localhost` to your current ip.